# build.gradle how to apply a closure from another file

Tags: android, groovy, closures, build.gradle

I have a closure of defined in a another build.gradle file called *other.gradle*. Here is the contents:

```
Closure callback =  {

    productFlavors {  
        ...
        devel {
            ...
        }

        prod {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now in my build.gradle file I want to call this closure like this:

```
apply from: 'other.gradle'
productFlavors(callback());
```

but I keep getting an error that callback() cant be found.  Both files are in the same directory.  My issue is how do i get the build.gradle file to see the callback closure in the 'other.gradle' file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be done in the following way:

**other.gradle**

```
project.ext.callback = { c ->
    println(c)
}
```

**build.gradle**

```
apply from: 'other.gradle'

callback('a')
```

Or in same cases `callback` should be referred via `project.instance`, e.g. `project.callback('a')`.